# Qt -how to get variable value from another function in same file

Tags: qt, qt5

New to Qt. Still learning it. I have clone.ui, clone.h and clone.cpp. clone ui has 2 buttons.

1. Browse button-> to Selection a destination path
2. Add button -> Clone(copy) a file

Clone.h

```
QString destination_path;
QFileDialog *fdialog;
```

Clone.cpp has

```
   QFileInfo finfo; // Declare outside function to increase scope
   QString destination_name; 

void Clone:: on_pushButton__Browse_clicked()
{  
  /*get the destination path in QString using QFileDialog 
    Got destination_path */

      QString destinatino_path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(....);
      QFile finfo(destination_path);
     // QFileDialog  finfo(destionation_path)  

 }`
```

In the same file Clone.cpp

```
    void Clone:: on_btn_Add_clicked()
   { 
      // how to get the  same destination_path value here... 
      //using QFile or some other way?    

    }
```

I struck here, Am i missing anything?  Any thoughts/suggestion highly useful.

Comment: getExistingDirectory returns a directory, and you want to copy a file, what is the file you want to copy?

Comment: want to copy executable  file. Once got directory path, file path will be "directory path+ executable file"

Answer (score 2):

You've create a class (`Clone`) which has a data member `QString destination_path`.

Since it is a member variable it has class scope (as in you can access the same variable in any `Clone::` member function for the same `Clone` object).

The problem is that you've *hidden* it by declaring **another** `QString destination_path` in `Clone::on_pushButton__Browse_clicked()`.

```
void Clone::on_pushButton__Browse_clicked()
{  
    ...

    // this *hides* the class member with the same name
    QString destination_path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(....); 

    ...
}
```

The solution is to remove `QString` from the beginning of the line, which means you are now assigning to the class object's data member.

```
void Clone::on_pushButton__Browse_clicked()
{  
    ...

    // now you're assigning to your object's data member
    destination_path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(....); 

    ...
}
```

Later, in `Clone::on_btn_Add_clicked()` you can access `destination_path`, and it will have the value assigned to it in `Clone::on_pushButton__Browse_clicked`

Comment: yes,correct. After removing QString ,  worked  as expected :) Cheers!